# Is there spring-data for CouchDB?

Tags: java, spring-data, couchdb, spring-data-couchbase

Can Spring-data be used with CouchDB?  I know there is a community project [Spring-Data-Couchbase](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-couchbase/) but is that compatible with CouchDB or does it only work with Couchbase?

If not, is there a CouchDB version of Spring-data?  Or am I unable to use spring-data with CouchDB?

Comment: Several years go I've used https://github.com/helun/Ektorp which in my opinion uses similar concepts to, e.g. spring-data-jpa (but I do not have a deep understanding of spring-data to tell for sure). Maybe that would suit your needs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/rwitzel/CouchRepository

This project provides a Spring Data API for CouchDB databases.

Disclaimer: I have set up the project.

Answer (score 2):

I found this old topic but I want to point out a new project called couch-slacker. The project contains spring data implementation in standard spring data way.

Check it out [here](https://github.com/Majlanky/couch-slacker)
Releases of the project are in maven central so it is very easy to use it.

Disclaimer: I am the founder and tech lead of the project